# Amazon api Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I'm using amazon product advertising api.

So I'm getting notices like "Trying to get property of non-object". Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Here is my code

```
if(!is_null($result->Items[0]->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormattedPrice) && $result->Items[0]->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormattedPrice != '0'){
                $output_str .= '<span class="amazon-ad-listprice"><strong>List Price: </strong>'. $result->Items[0]->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormattedPrice .'</span>';
                }
```

Here is the var_dump of that part

```
'ListPrice' => object AmazonProduct_Price (1)
protected _values -> array (3)
'Amount' => string (4) "3999"
'CurrencyCode' => string (3) "USD"
'FormattedPrice' => string (6) "$39.99"
```

I'm getting that notices only in products that doesn't have those values..

I've tried using isset(). But its not working.

Comment: The problem could be anywhere in the chain of `$result->Items[0]->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormattedPrice`; you have to inspect each chain to make sure it's still an object.

Comment: Hi yes it is an object. And its working in all other products except the products which does not has that "ListPrice" object. So i'm looking for a function which checks whether objects exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it all depends on the existence of `ListPrice` you could just write a simple condition:

```
if (isset($result->Items[0]->ItemAttributes->ListPrice)) {
    // do stuff with ListPrice->FormattedPrice;
}
```